# How to set IBOutlet for NSToolbar item in Xcode 6 OSX Storyboard

Tags: xcode6, osx-yosemite, xcode-storyboard, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I am trying to set IBOutlet for a toolbar item in Xcode 6 for OS X application using storyboards.  I have seen an example on setting a IBAction but it does not work for IBOutlets.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subclass NSToolbar and add the IBOutlet there.

Answer (score 0):

I recently researched the same issue. I found few helpful examples, but there was one that resolved the issue for me: Cocoa Programming L17. I was able to use Swift and adapt what he did to hook a toolbar item and a menu item to IBActions.

Update: I noticed the OP's issue was with a project using a storyboard. The process I referenced originally will not work with storyboards. But the process described in Google search "How to use NSToolBar in Xcode 6 and Storyboard?" nailed it for me. I need to learn how to make a link in my response.